# How can I transfer a file after having already logged in to a server via ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

This is a rather odd and embarrassing situation for all involved.

Suppose *someone* (*cough cough* not me *cough cough*) accidentally `chmod 000`d my home directory on a remote server.

I had been using ssh keys to login, since I figured I would forget the actual password on the remote host (which I have). However, now that my home directory has `000` perms, the ssh key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is unreadable, and ssh forces me to put in a password that I have long since forgotten.

Also, I don't have sudo superpowers on the remote server.

*HOWEVER*, I happen to have an ssh session open to the remote server that started before someone (*cough*) `chmod 000`d my home directory.

All of this happened while I was trying to upload some files from my local host to a publicly accessible directory in my home directory.

CAN I STILL UPLOAD FILES FROM MY LOCAL MACHINE TO THE REMOTE MACHINE WITHOUT NEEDING A NEW SSH SESSION?!

I figure I could at least put them in /tmp or something for now.

Comment: If you still have the ssh session, and you own the dir, can't you just `chmod` them back? (Give `chmod` the full path to the dir, don't try to do it from within the dir itself). [seems to work here](http://pastebin.com/ANed0rKd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

1. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>,<kbd>~</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open a ssh command line.
2. Enter `-L 12345:localhost:12345` to forward a new port over your existing SSH connection
3. Run `nc -l -p 12345 | tar xzv` on your remote ssh session
4. Run `tar czv FileOrDir1 FileOrDir2 Etc | nc localhost 12345` on your local system.

The files will now transfer over your existing ssh connection, and will appear in the current dir of your remote session.

Why you would want to do this instead of just `chmod 711 ~` is beyond me though.